# PHP simple html dom, selecting just a part of the content

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

Im using simple html dom to parse html.
https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Given the following code

```
<div class="item-price offer-price price-tc default-price">
$129.990
<span class="discount-2">-35%</span>
</div>
```

How can I select just the price?
Im using `$html->find(div.offer-price, 0)->plaintext;` but it selects the content of the span too.

Comment: I'm not sure about the library you're using, but in a proper DOM the `DIV` will have a list of child nodes, including the text nodes. The first child node of that `DIV` is what you want.

Comment: _"Im using simple html dom"_ welcome to one of the worst DOM libraries for PHP ever written. Consult the list in the linked duplicate

Comment: Ricardo, PHP has a great DOM implementation, along with XPath. Here's how I would do it with those built in libs. https://pastebin.com/8SrB62SB Hopefully you can translate it to the library you're using, or just convert your code to PHP's built in functionality.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I don't think this question should have been closed. Or at least not closed as a duplicate of "how to parse html with PHP." This is more of a question regarding understanding of the DOM than it is understanding how to get a DOM representation with PHP.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @JAAulde, your comments have been really helpful.

Comment: The question has been re-opened

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to do it in simplehtmldom, but you can use DOMDocument + DOMXPath to extract it,

```
<?php

$html='<div class="item-price offer-price price-tc default-price">
$129.990
<span class="discount-2">-35%</span>
</div>
';
echo  (new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html)))->query("//div[contains(@class,'item-price')]/text()")->item(0)->textContent;
```

bonus: both DOMDocument and DOMXPath are php builtins, no external library required to use em